# Typo in Stack Egg "winning the internet" message

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling, stackegg

I won the internet!!

I got the congratulatory message on winning, but noticed a typo:

[image: Picture of the "win" message for the Stack Egg, game; with the words "I doesn't get any better than that" circled]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. I've fixed the typo and it will be live in the next release (meta: ver > `2015.3.31.3224`, q&a: ver > `2015.3.31.2427`).

Comment: Thanks! That was pretty quick...I'll have to wait another 7 minutes to accept your answer :)